# Empty block in jQuery code

Tags: jquery

Line 4140 of jQuery 1.7rc1:

`while ( (elem = elem.previousSibling) && elem.nodeType !== 1 ) {}`

This is weird to my eyes. Is it equivalent to

`while( elem && elem.nodeType !== 1 ) elem = elem.previousSibling;`?

Comment: Whoa, I didn't know they do hacks like these in jQuery...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it is not equivalent to what you have.  The original code:

```
while ( (elem = elem.previousSibling) && elem.nodeType !== 1 ) {}
```

is equivalent to this:

```
while (elem.previousSibling && elem.previousSibling.nodeType !== 1) {
    elem = elem.previousSibling;
    // other code here
}
```

Logically, it says to loop while there is a `previousSibling` and while the `previousSibling's` `nodeType !== 1` and assign `elem` to that `previousSibling`.

The assignment in the original while condition is a shortcut that saves a separate assignment and saves an extra reference level in the `nodeType` check.

Breaking down the while loop even more, it's the same as this:

```
while (elem.previousSibling) {
    elem = elem.previousSibling;
    if (elem.nodeType !== 1) {
        break;
    }
    // other code here
}
```

This part:

```
(elem = elem.previousSibling)
```

assigns `elem.previousSibling` to `elem` and then evaluates whether elem is truthy or not.